# Using Generics as Parameters

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm still pretty new to both Java and Android and I'm working on an Android RSS reader project. I'm writing the reader that runs as an `AsyncTask`, and would like to keep it as reuse-able as possible. I'm using a SAX parser in the reader, and would like it to accept a handler of any type that extends `DefaultHandler`. However, when I try to call the parse method of the `SAXParser`, it doesn't understand the handler parameter.

```
cannot resolve method 'parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource,java.lang.Class<capture<? extends org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler>>)'
```

Is this the correct way to go about this problem in terms of passing a generic handler, or is there something I should be doing differently?

```
public class RSSFeeder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

private Class<? extends DefaultHandler> handler;
private String feedURL;

public RSSFeeder(Class<? extends DefaultHandler> handler, String feedURL) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.feedURL = feedURL;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    URL feedLocation = null;
    try {
        feedLocation = new URL(feedURL);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(feedLocation.openStream()));

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        sp.parse(new InputSource(in), handler);

    } catch (MalformedURLException murlex) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "The supplied URL is not valid " + murlex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Could not read data from the supplied URL: " + feedLocation.toString() + " " + iox.getMessage());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pcex) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Could not configure new parser. " + pcex.getMessage());
    } catch (SAXException saxex) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Could not create new sax parser. " + saxex.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does your handler extend DefaultHandler?

Comment: I haven't coded the handler yet, but yes, it will be. Do I need all the pieces in place for the complier to pick that up?

Comment: Well, to compile you need your code to satisfy lexical, syntactical and semantic rules, and proper types is part of that. @manouti gave some advice in his answer, so give that a try. It looks good :)

Comment: Yep, his answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handler` is a variable of type `java.lang.Class`, not `DefaultHandler` (or any of its subtypes). The second argument for the method `SAXParser#parse()` must be of type `DefaultHandler`. You can try declaring your class as a generic class with the type parameter extending `DefaultHandler`:

```
public class RSSFeeder<T extends DefaultHandler> extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
   private T handler;

   public RSSFeeder(T handler, String feedURL) {
      this.handler = handler;
      this.feedURL = feedURL;
   }
   ...

}
```

Comment: This has fixed it for me! So now my class is used in the same manner as ArrayList<String>? RSSFeeder<MyCustomHandler>?

Comment: Yes, like the `ArrayList`, it is a generic type now.